# rotação do carousel, não é possível ler a propriedade "style" de nulo

Tags: javascript, funções, carousel

Bom, estou tentando fazer um carousel em JS vanilla, porém, ocorre um erro na hora de criar a parte do script para a rotação do carousel

JS

```
//Cada Carousel
var bannersHolders = document.querySelectorAll(".banner-holder");
//Cada base para as imagens
var carousels = document.querySelectorAll(".banner-holder .carousel");
//Width e Height para definir os tamanhos dos carousels
var windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
var windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
//Definir width total de cada carousel
for(var iCarousels = 0; iCarousels < carousels.length; iCarousels++){
    var bannersInThis = carousels[iCarousels].querySelectorAll("figure");
    carousels[iCarousels].style.width = (bannersInThis.length * windowWidth) + "px";
    //Definir width de cada banner dentro de cada carousel
    for(var iBanners = 0; iBanners < bannersInThis.length; iBanners ++){
        bannersInThis[iBanners].style.width = windowWidth + "px";
    }
    setTimeout(function(){
        for(var iBanners = 0; iBanners < bannersInThis.length; iBanners++){
            carouselAtual.style.left = ("-" + (windowWidth * bannersInThis[iBanners])) + "px"
        }
    },5000);
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="banner-holder">
    <div class="carousel">
        <figure>
            <img src="assets/site/banners/banners_00.jpg">
            <figcaption>
            </figcaption>
        </figure>
        <figure>
            <img src="assets/site/banners/banners_01.jpg">
            <figcaption>
            </figcaption>
        </figure>
        <figure>
            <img src="assets/site/banners/banners_02.jpg">
            <figcaption>
            </figcaption>
        </figure>
        <!-- Adicionar banners com resolução entre 1440x1024 e 1920x1240 aqui -->
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
*{margin:0;padding:0;list-style:none;outline:none;text-decoration:none;box-sizing:border-box;font-family:"Proza Libre",sans-serif;}
html,body{height:100%;}
.banner-holder{width:100%;height:100%;position:relative;overflow:hidden;}
.banner-holder .carousel{height:100%;position:absolute;display:flex;}
.banner-holder .carousel figure{position:relative;overflow:hidden;height:100%;}
.banner-holder .carousel img{min-width:100%;position:absolute;height:100%;left:50%;top:50%;transform:translate(-50%,-50%);}
```

Erro

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

Como posso corrigir o problema ? O que o causou ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Testando seu código o erro que tive não foi na propriedade length de nenhum dos seus `querySelectorAll`. Obtive erro de declaração do carouselAtual que está no seu `setTimeout`. Acredito que você precise trocar esta linha de código:

```
carouselAtual.style.left = ("-" + (windowWidth * bannersInThis[iBanners])) + "px"
```

Por:

```
bannersInThis[iBanners].style.left = "-" + windowWidth + "px";
```

De qualquer forma, se a intenção é que o carousel fique trocando a imagem, o ideal seria utilizar `setInterval` e não `setTimeout`.

Comment: continua com o mesmo erro :/

Comment: quando jogo no console a função, ele aponta "-NaNpx"

Comment: Está acusando Not-a-Number no seu cálculo desse trecho:

`("-" + (windowWidth * bannersInThis[iBanners])) + "px"`.

Retorna um console.log de windowWidth  e bannersInThis[iBanners] para descobrir o que está trazendo este erro